# Country Select Gem in Rails 4 (gem 'i18n_country_select', '1.1.4')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I used gem 'i18n_country_select', '1.1.4' for country select but It didn't work, I already followed their short documentation. https://github.com/onomojo/i18n_country_select ..

or If you have suggestion gem that similar for country selecting that may help me.

### This is my form

```
<%= form_for([@user,@user_profile]) do |f|  %>

<div>
    <%= f.label :firstname, "Firstname" %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
</div>

<div>
    <%= f.label :lastname, "Lastname" %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
</div>

<div>
    <%= f.label :birthdate, "Birthdate" %>
    <%= f.date_select :birthdate, :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1920 %>
</div>

<div>
    <%= f.label :street_address, "Street" %>
    <%= f.text_field :street_address %>
</div>

<div>
    <%= f.label :city_address, "City" %>
    <%= f.text_field :city_address %>
</div>

<div>
    <%= f.label :country, "Country" %>
    <%= f.country_code_select(:user_profile, :country) %>
</div>

<div>
    <%= f.submit "Save Profile" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your error?
Shouldn't you use =country_select instead of =f.country_select ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this line:

```
<%= f.country_code_select(:user_profile, :country) %>
```

has to be:

```
<%= f.country_select(:user_profile, :country) %>
```

Please test it and let us know if it´s working